# Is it possible to implement an calcite adapter that supports INSERT/UDPATE/DELETE?

Tags: apache-calcite

All the adapters included in the calcite's repository are only supporting queries. I found there is a class called `ModifiableTable`, looks like it is for C/U/D operations. Is there any sample that implemented the `ModifiableTable`? I dug a long time and can not find one.

Comment: I'm interested in doing the same thing, so far, I hvaen't been able to figure out what to do once I have created an instance of my own TableModify.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, but there are are no adapters within the Calcite code base that does this. I am also not aware of any third party adapters which have done this. Although I say it should be possible, it's certainly possible that you will run into some challenges given that it's not a common use case.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible according to the docs - https://calcite.apache.org/docs/adapter.html#server

> Calcite’s core module (calcite-core) supports SQL queries (SELECT) and DML operations (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE)

You can see some examples in the tests

1. https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/296b84cad4406be03f2db35ce6077ad8fed4fef6/server/src/test/java/org/apache/calcite/test/ServerTest.java#L125
2. https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/4bc916619fd286b2c0cc4d5c653c96a68801d74e/core/src/test/java/org/apache/calcite/test/MultiJdbcSchemaJoinTest.java#L70
3. https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/sql/SqlInsert.java

I suggest checking out the code and looking at the adapter these tests are using.

I will be doing this myself in a few weeks so if you haven't figured it out by then I'll try to remember to post a more concrete example once I've worked it out :)

Comment: did you get to it and is there a public repo with any results? tnx!

Comment: No, we were evaluating calcite and some other engines at the time. We went for [datafusion](https://arrow.apache.org/datafusion/) in the end for a number of reasons

Comment: datafusion is in rust though so may not be viable for everyone.